# Html paint image to canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm stuck trying to Implement the imgOnClick(elmt) function so that it paints (to the canvas' drawImage() method) the image given by elmt.  elmt will be an  tag object.  The canvas has the id imgresult.
also In the document ready function, have each of the thumbnail images set their click event to the imgOnClick() function.

no matter how I set the code it won't work and I'm not sure how to do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="memeory.css">
        <title>Meme-ory :: Javascript Meme Generator</title>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            // TODO: set up the click events for the thumbnails
            $('#imagegallery').button.click(function){

            }

            // TODO: set up the click event for the button
        });

        // TODO: function called when a thumbnail is clicked
        function imgOnClick(elmnt) {
           var curImage = document.getElementById('memeresult');
           var thePath = 'images/';
           var theSource = thePath + elmnt;
           canvas.drawImage(elmnt, 10, 10);
        };

        // TODO: function called when the button is clicked
        function buttonOnClick() {

        };

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Meme-ory: Raging on in the Moonlight!</h1>
    </header>

    <main>


        <div id="controls">
            <form>
                <label for="toptext">Top Text:</label>
                <input id="toptext" type="text">

                <label for="bottomtext">Bottom Text:</label>
                <input id="bottomtext" type="text">

                <input id="createMemeButton" type="button" value="Give me Meme!">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="imagegallery">
            <img class="thumbnail" id="closeenough" src="closeenough.png" alt="close enough">
            <img class="thumbnail" id="cutenessoverload" src="cutenessoverload.png" alt="cuteness overload">
            <img class="thumbnail" id="deskflip" src="deskflip.png" alt="deskflip">
            <img class="thumbnail" id="lol" src="lol.png" alt="LOL">
            <img class="thumbnail" id="trollface" src="trollface.png" alt="troll face">
        </div>

        <div id="memeresult">
            <canvas id="imgresult">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: post your unsuccessful code so that we can find what's wrong